# How difficult is it to replace a car radio on a 2000 Honda Accord?

Tags: honda, accord, audio, replace

I have a 2000 Honda Accord LX. The radio works but the tape deck does not. I'm thinking about replacing it myself. I'm not looking to spend much on it overall so please let me know if this is something you've been able to do yourself and how long would something like this take?

Comment: so long as the existing radio is standard sized, and not part of the dash there should not be any problems,  replacing the radio in an '86 Mazda 626 was a real mission.

Comment: Replacing an odd sized radio in my Forester with a DIN sized mp3 player even required using a saw to cut back the fascia, so I'd definitely agree with Jasen - check sizing first.

Answer (score 5):

Not difficult really, if you're handy with a screw driver.

Hondas are usually pretty easy to pull the dash apart on, and [this guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Disassembling+1998+1999+2000+2001+2002+Honda+Accord+Stereo+Head+Unit/2440) will help you with that.

Then, it's just a case of installing your new stereo. Most "good" brands (like Alpine and so forth) will have adaptor plugs that can make it easy to go from your cars original stereo plug to the new one... So you won't even need to solder anything. Just plug and play.

I can generally swap a car stereo in and out within an hour, depending on how fiddly the car is. But it's not a hard job and one pretty much anyone can do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that particular make of car, but in the UK "standard size" radios are often held in the dash by a spring-clip device, not by screws. You need a pair of extractor tools like this: http://www.halfords.com/technology/car-audio/stereo-fitting-accessories/autoleads-car-audio-release-tool-pc5-83. Some cars require special tools for that particular design of radio.

You push the extractors into holes near the corners of the radio front panel (the holes may be covered by small blanking plugs or screws). When they are pushed fully in, the extractors unlock the retaining spring and latch themselves firmly the radio, so you can use the extractors to pull the radio out of the dash.

The only fiddly part is dealing with the connectors at the back of the radio, if you need to use an adaptor between the new radio and the original car wiring. Otherwise on modern cars you just push the radio back into place, and the connectors will line up automatically.